# Pasar un arreglo desde asp clasico a .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp, vbscript

Amigos, necesito pasar un arreglo desde asp clásico a una dll hecha en .net, y en .net espero un dato de tipo string[], como diablos hago para pasar ese dato desde asp clásico?
Hoy lo hago así:

```
Dim ws
dim arreglo(0)
Set ws = Server.CreateObject("Stc.ConsumoWS")
ws.SolicitarDesafio 3, 3, "", "00115594605", arreglo
```

Me da este error:

> ```
> Error de Microsoft VBScript en tiempo de ejecución error '800a000d' 
>
> No coinciden los tipos /PruebaStc/Default.asp, línea 22
> ```

Comment: como expones la libreria .net para ser usada desde vbscript ? la estas exponiendo como COM. Estas seguro que el CreateObject() puede crear la instancia del componente ?

Answer (score 0):

El error se produce al no estar declarada alguna función o variable. Comprueba que tienes añadida la declaración explicita de variables:

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" %>
<% Option Explicit %>
```

al comienzo de tu página en ASP en este caso.

En .NET declara las variables con algún valor inicial, para comprobar necesitarías publicar el código .NET aquí.  Pero el error que indicas es de ASP.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que he visto en [éste](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/z6cfh6e6(v=vs.110).aspx) artículo de la MSDN, creo que tienes que hacer dos cosas en tu método de C#

- El parámetro debe pasarse por referencia
- Hay que decorar el parámetro con el atributo [MarshalAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

La firma de tu método C# quedaría así:

```
public void SolicitarDesafio(
    int p1, 
    int p2, 
    string p3, 
    string p4, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType=VT_BSTR)] ref string[] p5)
```

En ASP Classic, el Array se inicializaría así:

```
Dim arreglo(2)
arreglo(0) = "valor 1"
arreglo(1) = "valor 2"
```

Y la llamada sería como la has puesto tu:

```
Dim ws
Set ws = Server.CreateObject("Stc.ConsumoWS")
ws.SolicitarDesafio 3, 3, "", "00115594605", arreglo
```